# Using localToGlobal to switch image positions

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to convert from coordinates of a parent container to global stage coordinates. This is the object and the container:

```
 imgSprite.addChild(imgInstance); //imgInstance is imported from class
 imageContainer.addChild(last); 
 imageContainer.addChild(imgSprite); // imgSprite and last are to be replaced
```

Basically, I want to switch positions of two images in `imageContainer`.

I applied the `localToGlobal()` function, but that hasn't had any effect. What did I do wrong?

This is my function that replaces them. Note: this code belongs to class `main`, parent of container is stage and every `imgSprite` is just added to `imgContainer` and moved via `obj.x`, `obj.y` (not in the code).

```
function click(e:MouseEvent):void {     
    var p1:Point = e.currentTarget.localToGlobal(newPoint(e.currentTarget.x, e.currentTarget.y));
    var p2:Point = last.localToGlobal(new Point(last.x, last.y));
    e.currentTarget.x = globalToLocal(p2).x; 
    e.currentTarget.y = globalToLocal(p2).y;
    last.x = globalToLocal(p1).x;
    last.y = globalToLocal(p1).y;
}
```

As I understand it, every object has local and global positions. So, here I convert a local position to a global, and then again when moving the other object to this position, I convert it to local, as they belong to the same parent it should result in matching coordinates, but my images start flying around in all directions and I start pulling my hair.

Answer (score 0):

```
var p2:Point = last.localToGlobal(new Point(last.x, last.y));
```

should be

```
var p2:Point = last.localToGlobal(new Point(0, 0));
```

The `Point` argument within `localToGlobal()` is the point within the `DisplayObject` that you want to globalize. So if `last` is located at (50,50) within its parent container, your code is really asking for the global coordinate of (50,50) within `last`. In this case, (0,0) *is* (`last.x`, `last.y`).